# Ajax data-table value is not fetching to the datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I want to fetch data form the database and show it with data-table. i have tied to fetch data with json format but data is not showing in data-table and i am unable to find to where is the error

here is my script

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            show_product(); //call function show all product
            //alert('hi');
            $('#mydata').dataTable();
             //alert('hi');
            //function show all product
            function show_product(){
                $.ajax({
                    type  : 'ajax',
                    url   : 'view_cat_table.php',
                    async : false,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        var html = '';
                        var i;
                        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            html += '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].date+'</td>'+
                                    '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-product_code="'+data[i].id+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-product_code="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>';
                        }
                        $('#show_data').html(html);
                    }

                });
            }


        });
```

**php code is**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `category`";
$fire = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($fire) > 0){
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)){
        $id = $data['id'];
        $name = $data['cat_name'];
        $date = $data['created_on'];

        echo json_encode(
        array("name" => $name,
            "id" => $id,
        "date" => $date));
    }
}?>
```

Comment: What is in your console?

Comment: This is not the right way to get  data for datatable ,you should see the documentation first

Comment: Okay, step back first, do console logs on what you get back, then check if you actually get a return. Further what I spot, is in your ajax an `async : false,` block. Is the block after it being executed or depending on it?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Comment: also, you create an array each instance, rather than adding to the original array, create a variable first for the array and then add to it, (in your php file)

Comment: You are encoding JSON data in each iteration of the loop, leaving that unrelated, while you should store  everything in an array and then encode it out of the loop.